# Login Window to Main Window in Prism (WPF)

Tags: wpf, wcf, authentication, prism, mef

I've been trying to figure out how to use Prism but I'm a bit lost right now on how to implement a feature on my small project... maybe I just dont know how to do it as I'm really new to WPF and the whole composition type of application as I was a Graphic/Web designer with an urge to learn more about programming. I friend of mine suggested that I should learn WPF and I did... I'm pretty good now with designing UI and the other things that makes it move. Last night I was able to write a WCF service and connect my WPF application to it which was really neat.

i was browsing last night when I found Prism and it got me really interested but I'm not sure how to use it completely... For now, all I want to know is how to wire a Login screen to a main screen using Prism.. most of the examples I've seen load contents to a shell window but I have not seen any that uses a Login screen that would redirect a user to a Main Window once a user is validated.

Can anyone point me to the right direction? A sample project perhaps? I know i'm not good at this yet but I'm eager to learn.

Thanks!

-Kiersten

Answer (score 2):

If you enter, for example, [this search query](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions?searchText=login%20window) in the Prism forums at Codeplex, you will get many threads that deal with this situation.

A particularly helpful one could be [this one](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=58292).

Searching for "login" also provides useful results, as many them explain what to do after the login has been performed, how to load modules depending on permissions, etc.